# Add horizontal space between list items enclosed in shape

Tags: html, css

I've made a list where the text is enclosed within a circle.  The issue is the circles run into each other horizontally, and I'd like some space between them.  I've tried messing with the padding and margin but have had no luck.

```css
.oval {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="oval">item1</li>
  <li class="oval">item2</li>
  <li class="oval">item3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexbox solution...

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  /* change this value as you need */
  width: 500px; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.oval {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="oval">item1</li>
  <li class="oval">item2</li>
  <li class="oval">item3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `display` to `inline-block` and then you can play with the margins

```css
.oval {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="oval">item1</li>
  <li class="oval">item2</li>
  <li class="oval">item3</li>
</ul>
```

To be more precise, instead of adding the `margin-right` rule for all `.oval` elements I would add it to all but the last one with:

```
.oval:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the display to inline-block to `.oval`